# Binding columns with similar column names in the same dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks somewhat like this:

```
df <- data.frame(0:2, 1:3, 2:4, 5:7, 6:8, 2:4, 0:2, 1:3, 2:4)
colnames(df) <- rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 3)
> df
  a b c a b c a b c
1 0 1 2 5 6 2 0 1 2
2 1 2 3 6 7 3 1 2 3
3 2 3 4 7 8 4 2 3 4
```

There are multiple columns that have the same name.  I would like to rearrange the data frame so that the columns with the same names combine into their own supercolumn, so that there are only unique column names left, for example:

```
> df
  a b c
1 0 1 2
2 1 2 3
3 2 3 4
4 5 6 2
5 6 7 3
6 7 8 4
7 0 1 2
8 1 2 3
9 2 3 4
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please also show what have you tried till now. SO is not a place to get your code written for free. Also telling what have you tried till now also shows that you are really looking to learn from the solution and are not just after solution

Comment: ...@geektrader but he provided a reproducible example, that get's him my upvote. In addition, the question is nicely limited, with a clear answer, which is confirmed by the large number of answers in just a few minutes. There are much much worse examples of people asking us to do their job.

Comment: @geektrader - Thanks for the welcome! I will definitely keep your advice in mind for the future.  And I assure you that I tried lots of things before posting.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I am not saying OP didn't try. I added that comment so that OP knows basic expectations of answerers here since OP is new.

Comment: @geektrader I understand, but your comment felt a little bit snarky. There are definitely posts that deserve this (one line posts "how can I do linear inverse bootstrapping with cross-validation in R"), but imo this question was rather ok. Therefore, I felt a need to comment back to you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will do the trick, I suppose.

**Explanation**

`df[,names(df) == 'a']` will select all columns with name `a`

`unlist` will convert above columns into 1 single vector

`unname` will remove some stray rownames given to these vectors.

`unique(names(df))` will give you unique column names in `df`

`sapply` will apply the inline function to all values of `unique(names(df))`

```
> df
  a b c a b c a b c
1 0 1 2 5 6 2 0 1 2
2 1 2 3 6 7 3 1 2 3
3 2 3 4 7 8 4 2 3 4
> sapply(unique(names(df)), function(x) unname(unlist(df[,names(df)==x])))
      a b c
 [1,] 0 1 2
 [2,] 1 2 3
 [3,] 2 3 4
 [4,] 5 6 2
 [5,] 6 7 3
 [6,] 7 8 4
 [7,] 0 1 2
 [8,] 1 2 3
 [9,] 2 3 4
```

Comment: This was almost identical to what I came up with, except cleaned up using `unname` - therefore: +1.

Answer (score 5):

My version:

```
library(reshape)
as.data.frame(with(melt(df), split(value, variable)))
  a b c
1 0 1 2
2 1 2 3
3 2 3 4
4 0 1 2
5 1 2 3
6 2 3 4
7 0 1 2
8 1 2 3
9 2 3 4
```

In the step using `melt` I transform the dataset:

```
> melt(df)
Using  as id variables
   variable value
1         a     0
2         a     1
3         a     2
4         b     1
5         b     2
6         b     3
7         c     2
8         c     3
9         c     4
10        a     0
11        a     1
12        a     2
13        b     1
14        b     2
15        b     3
16        c     2
17        c     3
18        c     4
19        a     0
20        a     1
21        a     2
22        b     1
23        b     2
24        b     3
25        c     2
26        c     3
27        c     4
```

Then I split up the `value` column for each unique level of `variable` using `split`:

```
$a
[1] 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2

$b
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3

$c
[1] 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4
```

then this only needs an `as.data.frame` to become the data structure you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use `%in%` and some unlisting

```
zz <- lapply(unique(names(df)), function(x,y) as.vector(unlist(df[which(y %in% x)])),y=names(df))
names(zz) <- unique(names(df))
as.data.frame(zz)
  a b c
1 0 1 2
2 1 2 3
3 2 3 4
4 5 6 2
5 6 7 3
6 7 8 4
7 0 1 2
8 1 2 3
9 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I would sort the `data.frame` by column name, unlist, and use `as.data.frame` on a `matrix`:

```
A <- unique(names(df))[order(unique(names(df)))]
B <- matrix(unlist(df[, order(names(df))], use.names=FALSE), ncol = length(A))
B <- setNames(as.data.frame(B), A)
B
#   a b c
# 1 0 1 2
# 2 1 2 3
# 3 2 3 4
# 4 5 6 2
# 5 6 7 3
# 6 7 8 4
# 7 0 1 2
# 8 1 2 3
# 9 2 3 4
```

Comment: +1, although the code looks quite daunting, but maybe much less so then some of the other answer...

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not at the computer now, so can't test this, but..*. 
 this might work:

```
do.call(cbind, 
     lapply(names(df) function(x) do.call(rbind, df[, names(df) == x])) )
```