# Gather groups of columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I have data from an online survey where respondents go through a series of 5 questions.
The data I am working at looks like this:

```
    P1 P2 P3 P4 P5  P1 P2 P3 P4 P5  P1 P2 P3 P4 P5
    1  2  3  4  5   1  2  3  4  5   1  2  3  4  5
    6  7  8  9  10  6  7  8  9  10  6  7  8  9  10
```

The desired output is:

```
     P1 P2 P3 P4 P5  
     1  2  3  4  5
     6  7  8  9  10
     1  2  3  4  5
     6  7  8  9  10
     1  2  3  4  5
     6  7  8  9  10
```

I have been trying to solve this problem with library tidyr, but i can't understand how to apply it.
Some advise on this will be really helpful.

Comment: Can you `dput` your data for us? Are you just looking to stack each set of 5 columns together?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803057/binding-columns-with-similar-column-names-in-the-same-dataframe-in-r

Comment: I suppose this works too: `data.frame(split(unlist(indf, use.names = FALSE), rep(names(indf), each = nrow(indf))))`....

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions can be:

```
require(foreach)
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)    

foreach(
  unique_name = unique(colnames(df)),
  .combine = 'bind_cols'
) %do% {

  df[grep(unique_name), colnames(df)] %>%
    unlist() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    set_colnames(., unique_names)

}
```

Comment: There is an extra `)` in your code